# Calculate $e$ and $f$ for $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt 3, \sqrt 2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I would like to calculate the ramification index $e$ and the degree of  residue field extension  $f$ for $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt 3, \sqrt 2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know the valuation of $\sqrt 2$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, hence $e\geq 2$, but I cannot go any further. I know that either $e=4$, $f=1$ or  $e=2$, $f=2$.
But neither can I find a  integer with smaller valuation nor can I find  a element in the extension of residue field.

I guess every minimal polynomial of integers of $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt 3, \sqrt 2)$, pass to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, is a  divisor of $x^4+1$ or $x^4$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$, hence the extension of residue field is trivial, so $f=1$, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: If $f=2$, there would be an unramified quadratic subfield. But can you show that $\mathbf{Q}_2(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbf{Q}_2(\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbf{Q}_2(\sqrt{6})$ are all ramified at $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (x-\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt2}-1)(x-\frac{-\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt2}-1)=
x^2 - 2 x + \sqrt2 x-\sqrt2$$
is Eisenstein over $\Bbb{Z}_2[\sqrt2]$

Comment: Thank you very much! But I wonder how do you find such an element.

Comment: With $f(x)=x^2-3$, $1$ is a root $\bmod 2^{1/2}$, $1+\sqrt2$ is a root $\bmod 2$, $1+\sqrt2$ is a root $\bmod 2^{3/2}$, but there is no root $\bmod 4$, so you look at $2^{-1}f( \sqrt2 (x+1+\sqrt2))$ and get the Eisenstein polynomial.